# Postman localhost server is not starting

Tags: postman, localhost

So, I am trying to make an API server on postman. Somehow it doesn't want to start. I know I have a **crap** computer, but I can run [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbBpN.png) many pages.

---

So, back to the problem. I am trying to run `GET localhost:3000/users?id=hiddenIDsoyoucanthackme` and it says this: 

`Hmmm… can't reach this page: localhost refused to connect.


Try:




Search the web for localhost


Checking the connection


Checking the proxy and the firewall


ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Back on the problem. Same at Postman.
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
**Help.**

Comment: Could you tell us a little bit about your problem? It is possible that this error occurs because your backend server is not working well.

Comment: @SmitGajera ok. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xiwdf-YkgkvPsmtPynpMfK6Z1c273yS5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Berriz, If you are using Vscode once try Thunder Client on Vscode you may find it in extensions, Thunder Client Same work as postmen works.

Comment: @SmitGajera No, you can't create APIs with thunder client